# Толмач - переводчик

Tags: этимология

Помните знаменитый диалог из "Ивана Васильевича"?

*Милославский: Сюда бы переводчика...

Феофан: Был у нас толмач-немчин. Ему переводить, а он лыка не вяжет. Мы его… в кипятке и… сварили.

Милославский: Нельзя так с переводчиками обращаться.*

Так вот, мне интересно, какая этимология слова "толмач" и почему оно не сохранилось в русском языке, превратившись в "переводчика"?

Answer (score 2):

С Фасмером в данном случае трудно спорить. 
Niemand не сказал, что это не просто заимствование, а заимствование с полным сохранением значения, что обычно является дополнительным аргументом.
Кроме того Фасмер дает не просто *версию* этимологии, но и достаточно широкий список родственных в близких языках: Слав. *tъlmačь является древним заимств. из тюрк.; ср. кыпч. tylmač, казах. tilmäš, тел., алт. tilmäč, тур. dilmač, уйг. tilmäži, что говорит о действительно древнем, коренном происхождении. 
Плюс ряд семантически близких значений в языках, родственных предполагаемому источнику.

Answer (score 1):

Фасмер говорит, что это древнее заимствование славянскими языками из тюркского. Немецкое Dolmetscher – заимствование из славянских.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы было понятнее искать ответ, необходимо понимать, о чём идёт разговор.  Толмач это придворная должность.  Нравы у правителей древности были крутыми.  За плохую новость гонца могли и казнить.  Донести новость до правителя,  хорошую или плохую, не навлекая на себя гнева,  в этом и было искусство толмача. Как видите, толмач и переводчик хоть и близки по значению,  имеют разную историю.

Comment: >Чтобы было понятнее искать ответ,  необходимо понимать, о чём идёт разговор.  Толмач это придворная должность.   

Это только одно из значений, не главная. Но даже если так, что конкретно это доказывает?

Comment: А доказывает это ошибочность, значения слов - переводчик и толмач. @andron молод и горяч.  Искусство толмача не перевод языка,  а разъяснение непонятных терминов.  Рыхлый язык полумертвого Брежнева.  Донести его мысль и донести ему мысль, не расплескав свой мозг. Или другой пример:  если математик расскажет вам решение теоремы Ферма, вы много поймёте? В какой-то мере толмач,  действительно учёный. Мощный интеллект, нисходящий до уровня серой биомассы. За что и ненавидим толпой.  Яркий пример:  расстрел автобуса с инженерами боевиками Игил.